# Code explanation - new to Java - Testing Automation framework

Tags: java

I am new to Java and trying to develop test automation framework. I have been following a tutorial. I am struggling with understanding a bit of code.Would be really great if someone can explain step by step as to how the code is working or any reference. Thanks is advance !

```
@Test 

   NewPostPage.CreatePost("This is the test post title").WithBody("Hi, this is the body").publish();
```

---

```
public class NewPostPage {

public static CreatePostCommand CreatePost(String title) {
return new CreatePostCommand(title);

}
```

---

```
public class CreatePostCommand {

private final String title;
private String body;

public CreatePostCommand(String title){
    this.title=title;

}

public CreatePostCommand WithBody(String body){

    this.body=body;
    return this;
```

### }

Comment: You're trying to develop a test automation framework? *Why?* There are three excellent options already (JUnit, TestNG, Spock), and it would be much better to start with a simpler project. Even with reference just to this question, you threw some boilerplate code at us asking an explanation of something, but of what is thoroughly unclear.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I will explain the code, since that is what you asked.

This is a **static** method, meaning it is a class-level method, rather than instance-level. You call it by using the classname followed by the method name.

```
NewPostPage.CreatePost()
```

It is defined by

```
public static CreatePostCommand CreatePost(String title)
```

It returns a `CreatePostCommand` object with the appropriate parameters.

```
return new CreatePostCommand(title);
```

The constructor for `CreatePostCommand` takes a single String.

```
public CreatePostCommand(String title){
    this.title=title;
}
```

Then, there is a Builder pattern from the `WithBody` method. The purpose of the Builder pattern is to chain together multiple `WithX` calls on a single line instead of using multiple lines for `setX` and `setY` methods. Each `WithX` call returns the object it is building.

```
return this;
```

Now, I guess you left out the `publish` method? But in all what you have is equivalent to this.

```
CreatePostCommand postCmd = NewPostPage.CreatePost("This is the test post title");
postCmd = postCmd.WithBody("Hi, this is the body");
postCmd.publish();
```